# Encoding when calling http.get

Tags: azure, angular

I am using paging with continuationToken in Angular2 and the problem is when calling http.get the token isn't encoded correctly and I will get a Bad Request error.

```
let token:string;

let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('maxItemCount', maxItemCount.toString());
params.set('continuationToken', token);

let result = this._http.get(`myEndpoint/lists`, { search: params   }).map((response: Response) => {
  let res = <ResultObject>response.json();
  this.token = res.token;
  return res;
});
```

Here is how the incorrectly encoded token looks like after calling http.get

```
https://apiaddress/lists?maxItemCount=5&continuationToken=%7B%22token%22:%22+RID:OsZtAJ7IPwCyAAAAAAAAAA==%23RT:1%23TRC:5%23RTD:lg4yMDE2LTExLTIxVDE2OjIzOjQ3Ljc5NjYwNTVa%23FPC:AgEAAAAUAEkAIBUVAFVVVVVVVVVVVVVFASoA%22,%22range%22:%7B%22min%22:%22%22,%22max%22:%22FF%22%7D%7D
```

Here is how a correctly encoded token looks like

```
https://apiaddress/lists?maxItemCount=5&continuationToken=%7B%22token%22%3A%22%2BRID%3AOsZtAJ7IPwCyAAAAAAAAAA%3D%3D%23RT%3A1%23TRC%3A5%23RTD%3Alg4yMDE2LTExLTIxVDE2OjIzOjQ3Ljc5NjYwNTVa%23FPC%3AAgEAAAAUAEkAIBUVAFVVVVVVVVVVVVVFASoA%22%2C%22range%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A%22%22%2C%22max%22%3A%22FF%22%7D%7D
```

I´ve tried encoding the token before sending it with encodeUri and encodeUriComponent the problem is http will re-encode it, encoding symbols like % which are part of the previous encoding.

Can I control how http.get encodes the token?

Comment: The problem was with the URLSearchParams if I remove it and manually create the url with the encoded token it works fine..